# Windows turns volume down when launching GTA and other game applications

Tags: audio, windows-10

For example, today I listened to Spotify with full power and clearly heard that when I started a game, in this case GTA, Windows turned the volume down by at least 50% or something. When I closed the application, sound is back to normal. Any solutions for fixing this irritating issue?

I'm using a complete new installation of Windows 10, a new Acer Aspire Nitro VN7-591G. I have not installed any sound-related applications or changed anything in audio settings.

Comment: If you click the `Volume icon` on the bottom right, and go to `Mixer`, ensure that all of the device and application sound levels are at the proper setting (try setting them all to 100%).

Comment: @Breakthrough All sound levels is at 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Dolby Digital Plus was turned off on my computer, turning it on did the trick. This is a strange one, but whatever works!

Answer (score 1):

Check under 'Control Panel\Hardware and Sound', tab Communications: Is it set to 'Reduce the volume to...'? Your game probably claims that it wants to use Audio, and even though it is not producing any sounds (yet), Windows turns down volume for the other sources.

You can just switch it there to 'Do Nothing'.
Be aware that when your game finally produces sound, it will overlay the other sound, and both will be full volume (and it will probably sound like you stepped on your cat's tail)

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If the solution posted above doesn't work, try going to Sound -> Speakers -> Advanced and uncheck the "Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device" field.